# Security advisories api

Tags: community-official-site

Is there an api to use to get data from https://www.drupal.org/security? 
I'm looking to get for example all vulnerabilities for older versions of a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three RSS feeds:

- [Core security announcements](http://drupal.org/security/rss.xml)
- [Third-party modules announcements](http://drupal.org/security/contrib/rss.xml)
- [Public service announcements](http://drupal.org/security/psa/rss.xml)

Using PHP, you can parse one of those RSS feeds to get the data you need.